# Can not read XML by simplexml_load_file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I was trying to read an xml file which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- UNCLASSIFIED -->

<!-- Built from ANZLIC MET Template ISO 19139 2009-02-18 -->
-<gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gml/gml.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink http://www.isotc211.org/2005/xlink/xlinks.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
<!--METValidation=False-->
-<gmd:fileIdentifier> <gco:CharacterString>D09C1546-5CB8-49AE-B717-E74FF3499F57</gco:CharacterString> </gmd:fileIdentifier>
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

I used  `$xml =  simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);` but I have problem with namespaces and colons!

Could somebody help me how I can read this XML?!

Cheers,
Arash

Comment: You say you "have problem with namespaces and colons", but you don't tell us what that problem is. There are lots of existing questions on this, but I'm not sure which to mark this as a duplicate of. The key functions are `->children($ns)`, `->attributes($ns)`, and (if you want to use XPath) `->registerXPathNamespace()`.

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I use "$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);" It returns error with reading the XML file, while when reading another XML without namespace, it is fine! I do not know how I can use registerXPathNamespace() when I have error in reading the file!

Comment: What is the actual error message you are seeing? Even if you don't understand what an error message means, you should copy the exact message so that others can see the problem you are having.

Comment: Thank you IMSoP, I finnaly overcome the problem by using: "$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
$elements = $sxml->xpath('//MD_Metadata/fileIdentifier/CharacterString');

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try `$xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], null, null, null, true);`</strike>

If that doesn't work, read up [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php). The last parameters of this method/function regard namespaces.  Given this XML document has many, it might be better to just use the SimpleXML class.

@IMSoP is absolutly correct; it's because you have to register the XpathNamespaces.

XML in 'file.xml':

```
<!-- UNCLASSIFIED -->

<!-- Built from ANZLIC MET Template ISO 19139 2009-02-18 -->
<gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/gmd.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gml/gml.xsd http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink http://www.isotc211.org/2005/xlink/xlinks.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
<!--METValidation=False-->
<gmd:fileIdentifier> <gco:CharacterString>D09C1546-5CB8-49AE-B717-E74FF3499F57</gco:CharacterString> </gmd:fileIdentifier>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

$xml->registerXPathNamespace("gmd", "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("gco", "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco");
print_r($xml->xpath("//gco:CharacterString"));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => D09C1546-5CB8-49AE-B717-E74FF3499F57
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't think passing that parameter as `true` will make any difference to how namespaced elements are accessed; it's just a case of knowing how to use the module.

Comment: @IMSoP - Could you reassess your downvote? Edit's have been made.

Comment: OK, downvote removed, but still no upvote. Unless you *want* to use XPath, there is no reason to do so just because namespaces are involved. If you want to use the actual SimpleXML API, you just need the `->children()` and `->attributes()` methods.